# How to encode characters in url with Alamofire on iOS

Tags: swift, alamofire, urlencode

I'm using Alamofire as network manager in my iOS App.
I need to do a GET request and send a value like this

```
DQIOE/LE/G77qpYbiMQPIuND2qrZjhS4f6kMDSr1+Zjxrq31QjdZZPNtbNjdmBBO3bHCJD8J+U5epkbr8SBqZi8wLM6DhOL0e//iky3N2Jum5fLM8yCFpJcpv0FRpuvTuiHnsu7W59Hx1h+XACdJ231xS9vOIMKxKfSmDMpw+QEoxMyogXQPIxqV4SbbH+etWHg+UEB3E5SuWag==
```

as query parameter.
I'm trying to use `URLEncoding.default` as value in the request but I always get error. Is there a way to automatic encode character in Alamofire? Or I have to made it manually before passing the url to the get method like this ?

```
let p = param.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.alphanumerics)
```

Actually this is the centralized function I use to perform all the GET http requests

```
func get(url: String, headers: HTTPHeaders?) -> DataRequest {
        return AF.request(url,
                          method: .get,
                          encoding: URLEncoding.default,
                          headers: headers)
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Percent escape only the base64 part, then add it to the URL?

Answer (score 0):

If you use AlamoFire's Parameters type, it should do all encoding for you. You shouldn't try to pre-encode the data, since it will then double-encode. If you're having an actual encoding problem, show how you're writing the `AF.request` and what is being sent and what you believe should be sent. But as a rule, don't try to URL-encode yourself. Use the tools like AF's Parameter or URLQueryItem, and let the system do the right thing.

Comment: this is the centralized func I use in network to perform http request

`
func get(url: String, headers: HTTPHeaders?) -> DataRequest {
        return AF.request(url,
                          method: .get,
                          encoding: URLEncoding.default,
                          headers: headers)
    }
`

Comment: Also pass the Parameters data structure to the `request` method rather than trying to build your entire URL by hand. It'll encode it all for you. If you want to build it yourself, then I highly recommend reading the URI spec (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) and carefully follow the encoding rules. Each part has its own requirements, so how to encode it depends on the details of the URL (which you don't explain). There's no single percent encoding that is always right. We'll need to know where this parameter goes in your URL.

Comment: To your question of whether AlamoFire can automatically encode, it absolutely can. Pass the parameters in the Parameters argument. That's why it's there; so you don't have  to learn all the rules. (But if you do want to learn the rules, the RFC is quite approachable. It's not magic; it's just complicated.)